# How to include library headers in CMakeLists

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, ros, catkin

I'm having trouble getting CMake and Make to find external header files I need to compile my code.

My code has is trying to use a header provided by the external aruco library

```
#include <aruco.h>
```

And when I try to compile I get

```
/home/ncr/ncr_ws/src/aruco_ros/src/aruco_ros_node.cpp:21:19: fatal error: aruco.h: No such file or directory
#include <aruco.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

My CMakeLists.txt has:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(aruco_ros)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/local/lib/cmake)
message( STATUS "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: " ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(aruco REQUIRED)
...
include_directories(
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${aruco_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
message(STATUS "OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS: " ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS "aruco_INCLUDE_DIRS: " ${aruco_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

The `Findaruco.cmake` file is in `/usr/local/lib/cmake/Findaruco.cmake`

The `Findaruco.cmake` file sets the `aruco_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable as `/usr/local/include` and the include file `aruco.h` is in `/usr/local/include/aruco`. Does make not search subdirectories? Most of the opencv headers are in `/usr/local/include/opencv2` but the `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` only declares `/usr/local/include` and yet all opencv the headers are found without any problem.

Comment: You need `#include <aruco/aruco.h>`. If you don't want to specify the subdirectory then add that to the path used in `include_directories`.

Comment: Thanks! Since you answered in a comment, is there any way I can upvote or increase your rep or whatever?

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend you not add the subdirectory to the path and specify the subdirectory when you perform the include. I like the context it gives about the source associated with the header (also helps avoid issues if headers are named the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James Adkison said, I needed to properly reference the header files. Looking at the other opencv include files, I start them all off with `#include <opencv2/[blah]>`, which explains why those work as well.

Comment: There you go, that works. Answer your own question and accept it. :) If I wanted to get rep I'd have provided an answer.